# NAT with iptables does not work from within a VM

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, linux-kvm, proxmox

I use Proxmox on a Debian 11 host with two public IP addresses.

One ip gets bridged to a virtual machine (VM1) via vmbr0.

For another machine (VM2, IP 192.168.10.2) I want to use NAT to get internet access and expose some ports to the internet.

I use the following network configuration. I obfuscated my public IP to 1.1.1.1.

```
#/etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo inet6 loopback

iface enp41s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 1.1.1.1/32
        gateway 1.1.1.255
        bridge-ports enp41s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 1
        pointopoint 1.1.1.255
#Bridge mode

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
    address 192.168.10.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    bridge_ports none
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
    post-down iptables -t nat -F
    post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 2023 -j DNAT --to 192.168.10.2:2022
    post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m multiport -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 80,443,5050 -j DNAT --to 192.168.10.2
#NAT mode
```

The setup works fine when connecting from the internet, but I can't access the main IP (1.1.1.1) from VM2 because the ports are not redirected properly.

I already tried adding `post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m multiport -i vmbr1 -p tcp --dport 80,443,5050 -j DNAT --to 192.168.10.2` but afterwards connections won't work at all.

Comment: Did you obfuscate your IP with 1.1.1.1? Or are you Cloudflare DNS?

Comment: I obfuscated it.

Comment: Sounds like you want to set `hairpin on` with `bridge link set dev $slave` or `ip link set $slave type bridge_slave` for the bridge slave that VM2 is attached to. Besides, unlike the `-i vmbr0` one, you probably *have to* add `-d 1.1.1.1` to the `-i vmbr1` DNAT rule.

Comment: Yes, its a hairpin issue. Local Processes are not subjected to the PREROUTING table, so the rules you made don't apply to programs running on proxmox itself.